# Why does not PRIMARY buffer work in VIM sometimes?

Tags: linux, vim, copy

I edited `/var/log/cups/error_log` with VIM and, as I usually do when I have to copy from VIM and paste at some place else, I used the PRIMARY buffer. So far it never failed; but this time it did not work. So I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with the same result: no copying. Then I opened this file with the pager `less` and I could do a copy and paste job all right. I just don't understand what's happening. Is there anything special about `/var/log/cups/error_log`?

ps : I've just tried */var/log/dpkg.log* and */var/log/kern.log* and the same problem occurred : highlighting a few words just triggered the VISUAL mode of VIM as it did with */var/log/error_log*.

System: Debian 11 / Xfce

Comment: it seems that the compulsory use of "sudo vim ..." to edit files in the /var/log/ directory is responsible for this behaviour . I verified this by opening a non protected file  with " vim .." and next with " sudo vim.." : PRIMARY buffer was available with "vim" but not with "sudo vim" . But as I am not a learned user this must be taken with caution .

Comment: Is the output of `sudo env | grep '^DISPLAY='` identical to the output of `env | grep '^DISPLAY='`?

Comment: yes , both displays are identical : " DISPLAY=:0.0 "